# UIWebView javascript with IOS Issue

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I try to use IOS call function from javascript but still not working Help me pleasee!!

this javascript

```
function geturl(getdata) {
   // document.getElementById('test1').src = '';
     alert(getdata);
}
```

and IOS code

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {

    NSURL *URL = [inRequest URL];
    NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",URL];
    NSString *urlString = inRequest.URL.absoluteString;

    NSString * getdata  = @"come please";
    NSString * sendBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"geturl('%@')",getdata];
    [subView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:sendBack];// subView is UIWebview

  return YES;
}
```

I try to use like this but data is not alert I don't know what happen help me please!!

---

```
  -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

        if (loadingPage < [book count]) {

            NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[book objectAtIndex:loadingPage] ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@""]];
            [[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:loadingPage] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
            [[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:loadingPage] setHidden:NO];
            loadingPage++;
            subView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
            [[subView scrollView] setBounces: NO];       
        }
        NSString * getdata  = @"come please";
        NSString * sendBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"geturl('%@')",getdata];
        [subView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:sendBack];


    }
```

I also try this one but still not working. If I got something wrong please tell me

Comment: What is subView here? Is it a UIView?

Comment: oh sorry// subView is UIwebview.

Comment: and I'm already try in `-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`  T-T

Answer (score 1):

please ensure subView is UIWebView object, and also you steel need return `YES` or `NO` in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method. 
And one more little solution - open safari debugger with simulator or device and check this function manually in console

Comment: `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` calls before any content loaded, so you need to add some check that is not first request, or move all code to for example `webViewDidFinishLoad`

Comment: Thanks,and I'm already try in `-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` T-T but Thanks

Comment: you are welcome, please also update question, or start another one